# compiler says method is undefined ... but it is (I thought)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to call:

```
public class Counter<MyClassSelectorObject> {

    final HashMap<MyClassSelectorObject, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    public void add(MyClassSelectorObject t) {
        counts.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
        t.setCount(counts.get(t));
    }
...
}
```

However I'm getting the following error from my compiler in Eclipse on `t.setCount(counts.get(t));`:

```
The method setCount(Integer) is undefined for the type MyClassSelectorObject
```

However I have

```
public class MyClassSelectorObject implements Comparable<MyClassSelectorObject>{

    ...

    public void setCount(Integer value) {
        this.count = value;
    }

    ...

}
```

The solution that Eclipse's quickfix feature offers me is to cast t to an Object, which makes no sense to me. Then again, I'm just getting back into coding after years away so I might be missing something basic here.

I'm using Java 8 and Eclipse Luna.

Thanks!

Comment: Removing the generic from the declaration of the Counter class seems to solve the problem, but I'm still not sure why (or whether that's the right solution).

Comment: `MyClassSelectorObject` in `class Counter<MyClassSelectorObject>` is name generic type, not name of your class. It is the same as is you would use `T` in `class Counter<T>`. It means that in `add(MyClassSelectorObject t)` `MyClassSelectorObject ` is also generic type, so invoking `t.setCount` is impossible since `t` is instance of some unknown generic type.

Comment: @Pshemo your comment was the piece of the puzzle that got me to understand the answers below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have done is declared a [generic class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) that has a generic type parameter:

```
public class Counter<T> {

}
```

Except your `T` is called `MyClassSelectorObject`...

So you have shadowed your `class` with a generic type parameter, you method is equivalent to:

```
public void add(T t) {
    counts.merge(t, 1, Integer::sum);
    t.setCount(counts.get(t));
}
```

As there are no bounds on `T`, the `T` is equivalent to `Object`.

As you have already noted, removing the generic type from `Counter` fixes your problem. Which begs the questions - why did you add it in the first place ...?

Comment: Wow, thanks guys. My first StackOverflow question answered!

@Boris the reason is that I originally wrote Counter to be a generic type that would count instance of any type that you parameterized it with. Later, I tried to simplify it to only work with MyClassSelectorObjects, but I'm a bit new to generics and got confused around the syntax.